# Basic Gatsby Shopify example missing Layouts

Tags: reactjs, graphql, shopify, gatsby

I am working with a basic Gatsby Shopify website template here https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/building-an-ecommerce-site-with-shopify/

I am trying to get this simple example up and running but I noticed in the following code block in

/src/pages/products.js

```
import Layout from "../components/layout"
```

there is no mention of components or layouts in the article and the app is throwing errors there. I am just trying to get a basic example to work. Is there a github link for this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Layout>` component is a common resource in mostly all Gatsby starters (the [default one](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default) for example), if you don't have it, just create the following structure under `/components` folder (to keep your code structure):

```
/**
 * Layout component that queries for data
 * with Gatsby's useStaticQuery component
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/use-static-query/
 */

import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Header from "./header"
import "./layout.css"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata?.title || `Title`} />
      <div
        style={{
          margin: `0 auto`,
          maxWidth: 960,
          padding: `0 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
        }}
      >
        <main>{children}</main>
        <footer style={{
          marginTop: `2rem`
        }}>
          © {new Date().getFullYear()}, Built with
          {` `}
          <a href="https://www.gatsbyjs.com">Gatsby</a>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

As you can see, the `<Layout>` component wraps the whole application with the `children` `prop`, sharing a `<Header>` component and a `<footer>` tag across all the applications when used.

You can remove `propTypes` if you are not using them.